# What it the order of ab where the order of a is finite, order of b is infinte

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

If $a$ is of infinite order and $b$ of finite order, does $ab$ necessarily have infinite order or does it depend on an individual groups structure?

Comment: For any $l,m,n \in {\mathbb Z}_{\ge 2} \cup \{ \infty \}$, there is a group with elements $a,b$ such that $a$, $b$ and $ab$ have orders $l,m,n$, respectively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Consider the group $\operatorname{Aut}(\mathbb Z, \{(x,y)\in\mathbb Z^2\mid |x-y|=1\})$ (this group is the set of bijective functions $\alpha\colon\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z$ such that $|\alpha x-\alpha y|=1\Leftrightarrow |x-y|=1$), and take $a$ to be $x\mapsto -x$ and $b\colon x\mapsto x+1$. Then $ab\colon x\mapsto -x-1$, and $(ab)^2\colon x\mapsto x$ is the identity, thus $ab$ has order $2$.

In other groups, $ab$ can have infinite order, as in the group presented by $\langle a,b \mid a^2=0\rangle$.